# How to use regular expression to find these exact characters on a list ( we iterate through a list)

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, python-re

So currently I run into a problem: I need to count how many times each  numbers appear in a string.
For example:  `Tran Yen Nhi sn 23 06 2003` should give the result: `{'0':3 , '2':2 , '3':2 , '6':1}`
I did finish it by using either regex or iterate through the text. But I'm trying to solve it in a different way. Here is my thought:

- If i can find all of the number '0' in that string using regex, it will return for me a list of '0'. Then I can use `len(list)` to find how many times it appears
- Same with other numbers, therefore I thought I need to iterate the number in `range (0,10)`
- Here's what I tried:

```py
for i in range(0,10):    
    number = re.findall([i],string)    
    count = len(number)    
    dictionary[number] = count
```

It got traceback: unhashable type: list. How can I fix this code? Thank you in advance for taking your time to tackle my question

Comment: why do you want to use a regular expression for that? Iterate the string and use a dictionary to keep track of the number of times each digit appears, or use itertools.

Comment: that's the first idea that I came up with and even though I solved it the other way around, it still bugs me xD

Comment: regular expressions are use to match certain patters of text, what you want to do according to the question is just count how many times a number appears in a text.

Comment: so may I wonder if this solution is unachievable

Comment: and if the question only asked me to find the '0' character, what is the syntax for it?

Comment: If you have found an answer that works for you, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the sequence, check if the character is a number and increment the dictionary count.

```
occurrences = {}
for character in my_string:
  if character.isdigit():
    try:
      occurrences[character] += 1
    except KeyError:
      occurrences[character] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in one line with [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a generator comprehension:

```py
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(char for char in string if char.isdigit())
```

Try it:

```py
print(counter)        # Counter({'2': 2, '3': 2, '0': 3, '6': 1})
print(dict(counter))  # {'2': 2, '3': 2, '0': 3, '6': 1}
```

Regex is not really necessary for this simple task, but if you want, you can match all digits with `\d` and then construct a `Counter` from that result list:

```py
import re

digits = re.findall(r'\d', string)  # ['2', '3', '0', '6', '2', '0', '0', '3']
counter = Counter(digits)
```

Note that the first argument to `re.findall()` cannot be a list. That said, `re.findall([i], string)` is the culprit behind the error. However, even if it accepts such an argument, `dictionary[number]` will also cause the same error since `number` will also be a list (`re.findall()` always return a list).

If you want to stick with your loop instead of `Counter()`, use [`string.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```py
dictionary = {}

for digit in range(10):
  count = string.count(str(digit))
  dictionary[str(digit)] = count
```

However, this will also record digits that have a count of 0:

```py
print(dictionary)   # {'0': 3, '1': 0, '2': 2, '3': 2, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 1, '7': 0, '8': 0, '9': 0}
```

The same goes with `re.findall()`:

```py
for digit in range(10):
  occurences = re.findall(str(digit), string)
  count = len(occurences)
  dictionary[str(digit)] = count

print(dictionary)   # {'0': 3, '1': 0, '2': 2, '3': 2, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 1, '7': 0, '8': 0, '9': 0}
```

Comment: Wooo your answer is very thorough. Thank you for sharing these. I appreciate it InSync

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems in your attempt to do it in that particular way:

1. `[i]` is not a valid first argument for `re.findall`. A string is expected. So pass `str(i)`
2. `number` is a list, so `dictionary[number]` makes no sense. You need `dictionary[i]`.
3. You only want to register occurrences when they are not zero, so you need an `if` guard.

Correction:

```
for i in range(10):    
    number = re.findall(str(i), string)  # fix first argument
    count = len(number)
    if count:  # don't register zeroes
        dictionary[i] = count  # fix the key: it is the digit.
```

NB: by giving better names you could avoid the second issue. As `number` is a list, I would name it with a plural. Also, a "number" can consist of several "digits". You mean "digit" here, so name the list `digits`.

Of course, this is not the most efficient way to handle it. You could use `collections.Counter`:

```
dictionary = Counter(re.findall(r"\d", string))
```

Comment: Thank you sm trincot. Exactly what I need. You break it down perfectly for me to understand